# Maximum call stack size exceed when using computed in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In the following code i want to load component dynamically based on value stored in the vuex store. But when I run this code then in developer console I am getting **Maximum call stack size exceed when using computed in vue component.** Computed function is running multiple time.

```
<template>
     <div>
        <component :is="layout"></component>
     </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { computed } from 'vue';
    import app from './layouts/app-layout.vue';
    import auth from './layouts/auth-layout.vue';

    import { useMeta } from '@/composables/use-meta';
    import { useStore } from 'vuex';
    useMeta({ title: 'My Title' });
    const store = useStore();

    const layout = computed(() => {
       return store.getters.layout;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you produce the error in a sandbox

Comment: Most likely, the `layout` getter has code that mutates its own value and, when read, because of that mutation, it triggers itself to be re-run. We cannot know for sure until you show it. Ideally, you should [import](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) the project in codesandbox to create a [mcve]. Without repro, chances to receive a useful answer are severely diminished.

Comment: Here is sample.
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-fire-rm2mqv?file=/src/App.vue) https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-fire-rm2mqv?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: a sandbox should reproduce the issue so that others may help debug and solve the problem.  this sandbox does not do that.  as tao hinted at, the issue might be in your vuex store so at least sharing your vuex code would be a good first step.